# How to get a Java Thread to notify itself?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread that handles operations in a queue. Basically, loop forever. If there are operations in the queue, dequeue an operation and execute it. If there are no operations, wait until you're told there are.

In pseudo code (ignore critical sections for now):

```
public class OperationHandler extends Thread {
    private Deque<Operation> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (queue isn't empty) {
                 dequeue the operation and execute it
            }
            else {
                wait;
            }
        }
    }

    public void operationRequired() {
        add operation to queue
        notify yourself / return to infinite while loop
    }
}
```

Basically a Controller class initializes this `OperationHandler` and `start()`s it. Whenever some requests arrives, the controller calls `operationRequired` on the thread so that the operations is handled asynchronously in the infinite `while` loop. Is there any way to achieve this?

I've tried with `this.wait()` and `this.notify()` but I get either deadlock or `IllegalMonitorStateException` depending on different synchronized blocks.

Comment: You can't. The question doesn't make sense. You are talking about one thread but also about asynchronous operations. What you really have is at least two threads. Please revise your question so it makes sense.

Comment: `operationRequired()` is called from another thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How to get a Java Thread to notify itself?

You can't get a Thread to notify itself since it is blocked in `wait()`.  You *can* have another thread notify the thread by synchronizing on the same object that the thread is locking on and calling `notify()`.  See the below code for a sample.

That said, I'd recommend using a `BlockingQueue` to share data in this respect.  It takes care of all of the locking and signaling.  All the thread does is call `take()` and it will wait for the next operation to be added to the queue with a `put()`.

Lastly, it's always recommended to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.  Once you turn your thread into a runnable you can use the `ExecutorService` classes as @Peter mentions in his answer.  With an `ExecutorService` your code would look like:

```
 public class OperationHandler implements Runnable {
     public void run() {
        // no looping or dequeuing needed
        // just execute the job
     }
 }

 // create a thread pool with a single thread worker
 ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 // or create a thread pool with 10 workers
 // ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
 // or you can create an open-ended thread pool
 // ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
 ...
 // do this once or many times
 threadPool.submit(new OperationHandler());
 ...
```

But if you still want to tweak your code to get it to work:

```
  private final Object lockObject = new Object();
  public void run() {
     synchronized (lockObject) {
        ...
        lockObject.wait();
     }
  }

  // called by another thread
  public void operationRequired() {
     synchronized (lockObject) {
        ...
        lockObject.notify();
     }
  }
```

Comment: …and that is why you want a BlockingQueue, take() will block until the other thread offers some work. All of this is nicely wrapped in an ExecutorService.

Comment: +1.  Runnable will also allow you to work with ExecutorServices

Comment: +1 frankly the OP appears to be pointlessly reimplementing ExecutorService

Comment: I'll only ever need one thread though so why have 10 workers?

Comment: It was an example for posterity.  You can use the `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` @SotiriosDelimanolis.

Answer (score 2):

If you notify() when there is no thread wait()ing it is ignored.  i.e. it makes no sense for a thread to notify itself because it cannot be waiting and notifying at the same time.

If you have a queue and thread you should probably be using an ExecutorService which wraps both. BTW It uses a BlockingQueue

Answer (score 1):

Your `operationRequired` method can't be called with the same thread if it is waiting. Although it is in the same thread class, it will be most probably executed with another thread.

So use normal synchronization: first enter monitor with `synchronized` then wait or notify. Another option is to use queues form `java.util.concurrent.*`. They support this stuff internally.

Answer (score 0):

Usa a `BlockingQueue` and its `take()` operation. It already has wait and notify embedded inside.